# Update Data While Creating Data Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I Have a form for creating a student profile like this :

```html
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="<?= set_value('email') ?>" readonly>
</div>
        
  
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
   <label>New Email</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="New Email" name="newEmail" value="<?= set_value('newEmail') ?>">
</div>
```

The **Email Form** is already filled with an email that students already registered.
But the Admin can **Update** the email with filling the **New Email Form** So it's not mandatory

---

I Tried Making it like this :

**Controller** :

```html
$id             = $this->input->post('id')
$name         = $this->input->post('name');
$birthdate = $this->input->post('birthdate');
$email         = $this->input->post('email');
$new_email = $this->input->post('newEmail');

if ($new_email) {
$this->m_notaris->updateEmail($id,$new_email,'tb_m_user');
}
      
$data_notaris = [ 
      'full_name'  => $name,
      'birth'      => $birthdate
];

$this->m_notaris->create_data('tb_m_notaris', $data_notaris);
redirect('master_data/Notaris');
```

**Model:**

```html
   

 public function create_data($table, $data) 
  {
        $this->db->insert($table, $data);
     return $this->db->insert_id();
  }
        
    public function updateEmail($id,$data,$table)
  {
     $this->db->set('email', $data ,FALSE);
     $this->db->where('id', $id);
     $this->db->update($table);
  }
```

But Then i got this Error :
[image]
Here is my **database:**

**tb_m_user:**

```
id      user_name      email

01      john72          john@gmail.com
02      karen_          karen@gmail.com
```

**tb_m_notaris:**

```
id      full_name      birthdate

01      John Christ    21-02-2003
02      Karen Clair    01-01-2003
```

Comment: Try this
$this->db->set(array('email'=>$data));

Comment: yeah it worked !

Comment: So approve my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->db->set(array('email'=>$data));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it